# Unsupported Resolution in GTA: San-Andreas?

Tags: technical-issues, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I just installed the game on my pc but unfortunately my LCD monitor isn't supporting its resolution or refresh rate.

My resolution is 1024x768 and refresh rate is 60Hz.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What resolution and refresh rate does your monitor use?

Comment: Resolution is 1024 x 768 and refresh rate is 60Hz.

Comment: If you have a file called `gta_sa.set` in `documents/gta san andreas user files`, delete it and try launching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deleting `documents/gta san andreas user files/gta_sa.set` resets settings back to default, which usually makes the game launch fine once again. You'll lose all your settings in the process, though.